# Universal Analytics - Conversion not sended to Analytics

Tags: event-tracking, universal-analytics

Here my problem : i placed code to track event on analytics but the event are not sended to analytics... so i cant trak them.

here the code ( I use UNIVERSAL ANALYTICS )

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46738558-1', 'restaurant-mon-repos.fr');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Now the code inserted in my page.

Pls note that i track different event on different button for different action on the page.

```
$op .= '<ul class="cro_directionscal">
                    <li class="dir-label">' .  __('To:','localize')   . '</li>
                    <li><strong>' .   stripslashes($postaddr)  .     '</strong></li>
                    <li class="dir-label">' .  __('From:','localize')   . '</li>
                    <li><input id="from-input" type=text value=""/></li>
                     <li><input id="to-input" type=hidden value="' .   stripslashes($postaddr)  .     '"/></li>
                    <li><input id="driveclick" class="" onclick="Demo.getDirections();ga("send","event","Bouton","Clic","itineraire");" type=button value="' .  __('Calculate:','localize')   . '"/></li>
                </ul>
                <p>' . __('The driving directions are interactive. Click on any bold text for further explanation of the route.', 'localize' ) . '</p>
                <div id="dir-container"></div>';
```

The second part of the code for an other tracking :

```
 $op .= '<input type="submit" onClick="ga("send","event","bouton","clic","contact");" name="cro_form_sub" id="cro_form_sub" val="" .   __("Submit","localize") .  "">';
```

I dont know if the dashes are the prob...

Thank you for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of code with 2 functions on the OnClick i have just cut the part of Google Analytics, then i have insert it directly inside the Demo.getDirections() functions and it works.

For the second part i replaced the (") inside the ga() function with : (\') escaped simple quote. It works too ! :)